# Linking words pronunciation /ng/

Tags: pronunciation, sounds

Just wondering if the [g] sound is sometimes used to link a word ending in [ŋ] and a word beginning with a vowel sound. For example, can "hang out" be pronounced as /hang-gout/?

If you know any helpful source about this inquiry, can you share it with me?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well, there is _lun-GUY-lind_ (Long Island).

Comment: Can it? Sure. Does it? Not in GenAmE. But with respect to @YosefBaskin's comment, in some varieties maybe. I don't know if the '/loŋ gai land/ in the NYC area generalizes to any intervocalic /ŋ/ (eg, does "sing a song" = /siŋ a soŋ/ or /siŋ ga soŋ/ there?)

Comment: @Mitch - I'm a New Yorker (which often almost sounds as if it should be written "Ñawka"), and yes, it does seem to generalize in that way.

Comment: Sometimes the /g/ is pronounced and sometimes it isn't. The word _longer_ can have two meanings -- 'more long', with the comparative -er suffix on the adjective _long_, and 'one who longs', with the agentive -er suffix on the verb _long_. The first one is much more common, of course, and it has a /g/ - /'lɔŋɡər/. But the second one does **not** have a /g/. One who longs is a /'lɔŋər/.

Comment: I was going to say that no BrE accent puts a /g/ in in Sandhi (In the NW Midlands and NW, all /ŋ/s are /ŋɡ/, even final ones). But I'm suddenly not so sure. I certainly say /ðəθɪŋ'ɪz/ for "the thing is", but I can hear /ðəθɪŋ'gɪz/ in my mind, and I don't think it's only Mancunians that say it.